# SQL convert decimal to numeric

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I need to convert my result into numeric form.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
select convert(float,round(avg(spelers.jaartoe),0)) as "gemiddelde toetredingsjaar"
from spelers
```

Comment: When asking such a question you should add sample data and the desired output, otherwise we do not see, what is wrong with your query.

Comment: Wait do you want numeric or floating point? They are quite different types. One is exact (numeric) and one is approximate (float).

Comment: Either way you should be able to just cast it:

select 1000::numeric(10,4);

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(floor(avg(spelers.jaartoe))as float) as "gemiddelde toetredingsjaar" from spelers
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: SELECT convert(decimal(10,2),round(avg(spelers.jaartoe),0)) ...
                                    ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
SQL state: 42601
Character: 29

Comment: @ThomasWouters which db system? and spelers.jaartoe is which type?

Comment: spelers.jaartoe is just decimal I think.

Comment: did you try SELECT ROUND(avg(spelers.jaartoe)::numeric,0)  ?

Comment: i tried : select cast(round(avg(spelers.jaartoe))as numeric) as "gemiddelde toetredingsjaar"
from spelers

Comment: but my school exercice told its fault

Comment: select cast(floor(avg(spelers.jaartoe))as float) as "gemiddelde toetredingsjaar"
from spelers

Comment: @ThomasWouters but the it is not rounded anymore as you did in your first example. anyways, as it is working for you. i updated the answer